# Recursive function for summations

Tags: java, recursion

I have to write a static recursive method to solve arithmetic summations and print the values of the parameters on each call.  Basically I have to add up all of the numbers between a lower limit and upper limit and print out "0+1 = 1, 1+2 = 3, 3+3 = 6, etc.." and then the final sum.

I have it so it accurately calculates the final sum but it always prints everything a few times. Can someone help me fix the printing stage of the method?
Here's what I have so far:

```
public static int summationCalc(int lowerBound,  int upperBound)
{
    int sum = 0;


    if(lowerBound!= upperBound)
    {


        sum = upperBound + summationCalc(lowerBound, (upperBound-1));
        System.out.println(upperBound + " + " + summationCalc(lowerBound, (upperBound-1)) + " = " + sum);

        return sum;
    }

    else
        return upperBound;


}
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: it's not going to look like what you've printed in your question. it will look like `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 5 = 6 = 6`. i didn't consider newlines here

Comment: actually, it will be other way around, first the upperbound is printed, then for each stack, the upperbound - 1 is printed, then all the sums.

Answer (score 2):

You were calling the recursive function twice.

```
 public static int summationCalc(int lowerBound, int upperBound)
        {
            int sum = 0;


            if (lowerBound != upperBound)
            {
                int k = summationCalc(lowerBound, (upperBound - 1));
                sum = upperBound + k;
                System.out.println(upperBound + " + " + k + " = " + sum);
                return sum;
            }
            else
                return upperBound;


        }
```

**Output from 0 to 3 :**

```
1 + 0 = 1
2 + 1 = 3
3 + 3 = 6
```

Comment: It does the same thing. It prints all of the lines a few times. for 0 to 3 it prints:

1 + 0 = 1
1 + 0 = 1
3 + 1 = 3
1 + 0 = 1
1 + 0 = 1
3 + 1 = 3
6 + 3 = 6
6

Comment: @user3266115 this is spot on unless you are calling this method from your main differently?

Comment: @user3266115 How are you calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. First of all, you are calling the method twice, and hence your sum will be wrong as the sum variable will miss every other variable.

You should think about how you want the answers to be printed, print it like that first, and then call the method recursively.